# Iterating over years for features in feature collection using Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-fusion-tables, google-earth-engine

I am currently working with the Hansen data ([Global Forest Change](http://earthenginepartners.appspot.com/science-2013-global-forest/download_v1.3.html)) in Earth Engine. I have also imported a fusion table representing districts in a specific country. My goal is as follows:

I would like to create a table which aggregates deforestation data for each district in the feature table. For example, a given district ('feature') should eventually have the following associated properties: sum of gained forest area for each year, sum of lost forest area for each year, and base year tree cover. Once all of those are gathered, I plan to export the data.

I have figured out how to do this for one year, but the problem is I can't figure out how to iterate over years without doing everything manually. I am also not entirely sure whether my filtering actually gives me the year that I expect, as I copied the filtering from an example in the tutorials.

Here is some of my current code, which aggregates the tree cover for each district, and adds a 'loss' property to that feature collection:

```js
//Load and filter the Hansen data
var gfc2014 = ee.Image('UMD/hansen/global_forest_change_2015').select(['treecover2000','loss','gain','lossyear']);

//add country districts as a feature collection
var distr = ee.FeatureCollection('ft:1U7sXFHXtxQ--g7XMeXlvPhNXPBcDtPg8Yzr2pvsg', 'geometry');

//look at tree cover, find the area
var treeCover = gfc2014.select(['treecover2000']);
var areaCover = treeCover.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea());

var lossIn2001 = gfc2014.select(['lossyear']).eq(1);
var areaLoss = lossIn2001.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea());

//need to check that .eq(1) is actually returning data for
//2001
var gainIn2001 = gfc2014.select(['gain']).eq(1);
var areaGain = gainIn2001.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea());

var districtSums = areaCover.reduceRegions({
  collection: distr,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
  scale: 100,
});

//This function computes pixels lost for each district
var addLoss = function(feature) {
  var loss = areaLoss.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
    geometry: feature.geometry(),
    scale: 100
  });
  return feature.set({loss2001: loss.get('lossyear')});
};

// Map the area getting function over the FeatureCollection.
var areaLosses = districtSums.map(addLoss);
```

I have looked to the following pages for help, but unfortunately neither appears to answer my question:

- [Using reducer over space and time in Google Earth Engine?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/243519/earth-engine-using-reducer-over-space-and-time)
- [Computing ndvi 10 yr. time-series from fusion table features using Google Earth Engine?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/244707/earth-engine-ndvi-10-yr-time-series-from-fusion-table-features)

This is my first time working with geographic data so the data structures are not intuitive to me yet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are filtering year in the correct way. This is how I'd do it:

```js
//Load and filter the Hansen data
var gfc2014 = ee.Image('UMD/hansen/global_forest_change_2015')
              .select(['treecover2000','loss','gain','lossyear']);

// list for filter iteration
var years = ee.List.sequence(1, 14)

// turn your scale into a var in case you want to change it
var scale = gfc2014.projection().nominalScale()

//add country districts as a feature collection
var distr = ee.FeatureCollection('ft:1U7sXFHXtxQ--g7XMeXlvPhNXPBcDtPg8Yzr2pvsg', 'geometry');

//look at tree cover, find the area
var treeCover = gfc2014.select(['treecover2000']);

// most recent version of Hansen's data has the treecover2000 layer
// ranging from 0-100. It needs to be divided by 100 if ones wants
// to calculate the areas in ha and not hundreds of ha. If not, the
// layers areaLoss/areaGain are not comparable to the areaCover. Thus
treeCover = treeCover.divide(100); // Thanks to Bruno

var areaCover = treeCover.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea())
                .divide(10000).select([0],["areacover"])

// total loss area
var loss = gfc2014.select(['loss']);
var areaLoss = loss.gt(0).multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea()).multiply(treeCover)
               .divide(10000).select([0],["arealoss"]);

// total gain area
var gain = gfc2014.select(['gain'])
var areaGain = gain.gt(0).multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea()).multiply(treeCover)
               .divide(10000).select([0],["areagain"]);

// final image
var total = gfc2014.addBands(areaCover)
            .addBands(areaLoss)
            .addBands(areaGain)

Map.addLayer(total,{},"total")

// Map cover area per feature
var districtSums = areaCover.reduceRegions({
  collection: distr,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
  scale: scale,
});


var addVar = function(feature) {

  // function to iterate over the sequence of years
  var addVarYear = function(year, feat) {
    // cast var
    year = ee.Number(year).toInt()
    feat = ee.Feature(feat)

    // actual year to write as property
    var actual_year = ee.Number(2000).add(year)

    // filter year:
    // 1st: get mask
    var filtered = total.select("lossyear").eq(year)
    // 2nd: apply mask
    filtered = total.updateMask(filtered)

    // reduce variables over the feature
    var reduc = filtered.reduceRegion({
      geometry: feature.geometry(),
      reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
      scale: scale,
      maxPixels: 1e13
    })

    // get results
    var loss = ee.Number(reduc.get("arealoss"))
    var gain = ee.Number(reduc.get("areagain"))

    // set names
    var nameloss = ee.String("loss_").cat(actual_year)
    var namegain = ee.String("gain_").cat(actual_year)

    // alternative 1: set property only if change greater than 0
    var cond = loss.gt(0).or(gain.gt(0))
    return ee.Algorithms.If(cond, 
                            feat.set(nameloss, loss, namegain, gain),
                            feat)

    // alternative 2: always set property
    // set properties to the feature
    // return feat.set(nameloss, loss, namegain, gain)
  }

  // iterate over the sequence
  var newfeat = ee.Feature(years.iterate(addVarYear, feature))

  // return feature with new properties
  return newfeat
}

// Map over the FeatureCollection
var areas = districtSums.map(addVar);

Map.addLayer(areas, {}, "areas")
```

In that script you get 3 fields: loss_{year}, gain_{year}, sum
But if you want better 4 fields: loss, gain, year, sum; change for:

```js
return ee.Algorithms.If(cond, 
                        feat.set("loss", loss, "gain", gain, "year", actual_year), 
                        feat)
```

You could also compute percentage and set it to the features.

**Edit**:
Thank to @Bruno_Conte_Leite, who made me reconsider my answer, I have made some updates, the one suggested by Bruno and others.

1. **Scale**:
   I suggest to keep the original scale of Hansen data.
2. **treeCover**:
   most recent version of Hansen's data has the treecover2000 layer ranging from 0-100. It needs to be divided by 100 if ones wants to calculate the areas in ha and not hundreds of ha. (Bruno)
3. **areaLoss** and **areaGain**:
   Added `.multiply(treeCover)` otherwise the area would be of the whole pixel and not of the indicated percentage
4. **maxPixels**: I added `maxPixels: 1e13` in the reduction

Comment: Thank you! If you can, I would appreciate you taking a look at one of my other questions as well: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/246561/aggregating-image-information-over-two-features-in-google-earth-engine